# Cannot access a variable of other view

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;
    NSInteger userID = gesture.view.tag;

    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle:nil];
    OthersProfile *vc = (OthersProfile*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"othersprofile"];
    NSString *strUserID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)userID];

    vc.userID = strUserID;
    [self.viewController.navigationController pushViewController:vc
                                                        animated:YES];
```

I am trying to access another view's variable and assign a value.

I declared that userID var on another view as

```
var userID = String()
```

But it says `Property 'userID' not found on object of type 'OthersProfile *'?`

Any idea how can i fix this?

Comment: try to change `(OthersProfile*)[storyboard` to `(UIViewController*)[storyboard`

Comment: @Lu_ having Incompatible pointer types initializing 'OthersProfile *' with an expression of type 'UIViewController *'

Answer (score 0):

Check the access modifiers on the `var` and its parent class.

this declaration

```
class OthersProfile:UIVIewController {
    var userID = String()
}
```

will not always expose your inner variable. It depends on your project setup.

You can always check the contents of the "MyModule-Swift.h" synthetic header by Command-clicking it to see what has been exposed by the Swift compiler and how it has converted the Swift attributes to Objective-C

You want to get something like this

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC5MyModule22OthersProfile")
@interface OthersProfile : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* _Nonnull userID;
```

The easiest way through is to start marking inaccessible things as `public` or `open` e.g

```
public class OthersProfile:UIVIewController {
    var userID = String()
}
```

or

```
class OthersProfile:UIVIewController {
    public var userID = String()
}
```

Later on you can back the access off if important.

Comment: I have one problem now. Every time I build the project it disappears from -swift.h file. How can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but don’t worry too much about the -swift.h file. it’s built dynamically. The reason you would inspect it is for your original problem.

Comment: Sorry but this answered seemed working at first but it results in a crash basically noticing there is no userID property

Comment: What could be the reason that userID property is not listed on -swift.h file?

Comment: Show the relevant swift code. Without that it’s a guessing game.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know nothing about objective C, but to me... probabily the problem is your cast.

Please verify what type is your VC with X-Code.. probabily is a ViewControler... and not your CustomViewControler.