# Accessing a swift property from objC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swift4

```
- (void) tapGesture: (id)sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;
    NSInteger userID = gesture.view.tag;

    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle:nil];
    OthersProfile *vc = (OthersProfile*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"othersprofile"];
    NSString *strUserID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)userID];

    vc.userID = strUserID;
    [self.viewController.navigationController pushViewController:vc
                                                        animated:YES];
}
```

It used to work with Xcode 8 / Swift 3 but seems like there is a problem with Xcode 9 and swift 4.

I am having property userID not found error.

In Swift file:

```
var userID : String = ""
override func viewDidLoad() {
    print(userID) //no value here
}
```

Anyone with any idea?

Comment: Are you sure this code was working in XCode8?

Comment: @PuneetSharma sorry i updated my question

Comment: Swift 4 does not expose everything to the Objective-C runtime anymore, so you may have to annotate the property with `@objc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
@objc var userID : String = "
```

The rules for exposing Swift code to Objective-C have *changed* in Swift 4. As such, your code was okay in Swift 3 and hence the confusion you are facing ;)

The new design is fully detailed in [the corresponding Swift Evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md).

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz ...this is, unfortunately, a *very* common issue when migrating from Swift 3 to 4 :-(

Answer (score 0):

Addression your other question you should fix how you access controller:

This is because `vc.user` is nil when you are trying to set it, add a variable to swift controller and set it instead of `vc.user.text

```
vc.yourVariable = strUserID;
[self.viewController.navigationController pushViewController:vc
                                                    animated:YES];
```

then in viewDidAppear you will be able to set it with this variable

```
 @IBOutlet var user: UILabel!
 public var yourVariable: String = ""

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     user.text = yourVariable
     print(user.text!) //should be value

 }
```

Comment: I tried this but this time I am having Property 'userID' not found on object of type 'OthersProfile *'? error. Check my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46754687/cannot-access-a-variable-of-other-view/46755098?noredirect=1#comment80464520_46755098

Comment: did you import your file to see this variables?

Comment: I didn't understand your question?

Comment: i did upate answer, check if setting variable `public` helps